# Set session tracking mode to cookie in Servlet 2.5

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jsessionid, servlet-2.5

How can i set the session tracking mode to only use the cookies, i can set this in Servlet 3.0 by setting the `<tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>` in the web.xml or by using `currentSession.getServletContext().setSessionTrackingModes(EnumSet.of(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE))`, but sadly these two methods only work for servlet 3.0 and i need to fix it for Weblogic 11g and tomcat 6 which supports servlet 2.5

Answer (score 0):

For Tomcat 6 you can set disableURLRewriting="true" on the Context which will leave Cookies as the only way to track sessions.

Comment: i was aware of this option, the problem is that i have a web application that need to run on tomcat 6 and 7 and weblogic 11g and websphere 7 and 8 and 8.5, i am searching for some application configuration that works for all these containers without the need to do any container specific changes.